# Serve sitemap.xml file on vuejs/express application

Tags: apache, express, vue.js

I can not figure out how to just serve the sitemap.xml file when hitting the url "https:example.com/sitemap.xml". I've tried everything from sitemap generating middleware to rewrite rules in Apache. I am just trying get google to register the sitemap for my application.

Comment: Do you perhaps have a catch-all route for VueJS routes?

Comment: Yes, I do have a catch all set up.

Comment: So is your sitemap route not perhaps caught by the catch-all route?

Comment: I created a new route for the sitemap, but I am not sure how to just serve the sitemap.xml instead of the Vue app.